# wxpython balloonframe overlays all windows

Tags: python, linux, wxpython

I am using `BalloonTip` and `BalloonFrame` from wxpython in order to generate pop up notifications. Unfortunately the generated elements are overlapping all windows: Not only the window of my application but also all windows of the other applications.

[image: Visualization]

I would like to suppress this behavior and display the notification only on top of my own application and not on top of all windows.

Is there any possibility to specify the "z-index" like in CSS or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably just create your own frame then as I don't believe the Balloon widgets support that behavior. When you do create your own frame, you can tell it to center on parent. If you want it to disappear on it's own, you can use a wx.Timer. You could also look at this:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/adv.NotificationMessage.html